# Broken packages after kernel update to 3.16

Tags: package-management, kernel

On a 14.04 system, I upgraded the kernel to 3.16 using:

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic`

Now a lot of packages like `unity-control-center` are broken. Also, refuses to install again. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you post the error you get when you try to reinstall unity-control-center,...

Comment: Hey! Sorry I don't remember the exact message now. But it said some packages were being held back

Answer (score 3):

The main issue was Intel Graphics Installer. Remove it and the PPA. Then do `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` to recover all the broken packages

Answer (score 2):

My only solution was to revert back to the old setup.

1. Uninstall the kernel 3.16 with (replace the version with the right one)

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.4.0-* linux-headers-3.4.0-*
   ```
2. Remove everything which brought on the problem.

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
   ```
3. Install the old version of these removed things with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic xserver-xorg libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa-drivers
   ```
4. Reinstall Ubuntu desktop.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
   ```